# Should I flag close-worthy proposals on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, flags, area-51

I came across a clearly non-viable proposal on Area 51, and I considered flagging it as such. The only options in the flag dialog, however, were spam, offensive, or a custom mod attention reason. Since "not a viable proposal" wasn't in the list, that makes me think flags shouldn't be used for that. Is that right? Should I do anything about close-worthy proposals? I wouldn't want people to spend time promoting them just to have them closed when they reach a certain milestone.

Comment: The proposal that prompted this question: [Home-work site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101434/home-work-site?referrer=oPzep-nsJlMXOJA16U4lGQ2).

Comment: Yes, you should flag them, by using the flag option "in need of moderator intervention"

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would rollback my edit that copied the link from your comment into your question.  Doesn't citing an example help to promote discussion of the issue that you have raised?

Comment: @PolyGeo I rolled it back because I was trying not to call out or shame anyone in the main post. Putting the link in the comments section was intentional.

Answer (score 2):

You could flag any Area51 site that you consider to be seriously non-viable using the Requires Moderator attention flag which will then let you type in why you think the site proposal is problematic.

[image]

Comment: Note that not every proposal you see that is *probably* unviable needs immediate attention. We have put [automatic checks](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51) in place that ensure a certain amount of activity before a proposal can continue through, for example. I'm not saying "don't signal problems", but do be judicious in what you flag for this reason. Most proposals are harmless when it comes to just letting them run their course.